# How can I auto fit the columns in an access table through Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

So basically I've created a macro to format a sheet in a certain way and I've got a code which exports and stores this info in an access database.

The thing is that the columns are the default size and not auto fitted. How can I auto fit the columns in access through Excel vba. I've tried googling and searching online but I can only seem to find formats from access to Excel. Not Excel to access. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which columns are you talking about when you say *"The thing is that the columns are the default size and not auto fitted."* Can you show a screenshot? If you are talking about an Access table then there is probably no solution for this.

Comment: It's not letting me add a picture for some reason, so I'll try and explain better. Do you know when you create a table in access our Excel, the size of the cell is the size that Excel sets it. If your character length is higher than what can fit in the cell, the cell size won't change unless you double click on the top of the column or drag the columns to the size of your own choosing

Comment: As I said: If you are talking about an Access table then there is probably no solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access tables don't support autofit.

You can influence column width in Access through `CurrentDb.TableDefs("TableNameOrNumber").Fields("FieldNameOrNumber").Properties!ColumnWidth`.

However, the common value for autofit, -2, doesn't work for this property, and just sets it to the default width.

That means you have to calculate the width of a certain table column, or copy the width from Excel if you're using identical font settings.

Comment: So do you write it as: CurrentDb.TableDefs("TableNameOrNumber").Fields("FieldNameOrNumber").Properties!ColumnWidth = 1. Or have I done something wrong because when I did this, the column disappeared

Comment: Eh, you've just set the column width to 1 twip, I'd expect it to disappear. -1 = default width, -2 = autofit (doesn't work), and else the width gets interpreted as a value in twips.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know the units were in twips. I've done what you've suggested and it works properly. I've been looking for a solution to this for a while, so I appreciate it. Thanks again